# How can I open a web browser on a server that I can connect to through ssh?

Tags: apache, perl, unix, ssh, server

I'm in a computer science program at my university (Ryerson) and I'm learning perl programming.

The way we're learning is by hosting perl scripts on our university's server and doing stuff with them.

I'm away from the university and the university's server is very strict about which IP's can use the www2 subdomain (which is the subdomain that runs perl scripts). And the IP I'm working from gets me the error:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /~w3dixon/cgi-bin/lab4.cgi on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at www2.scs.ryerson.ca Port 80

[Here's the link, if you want to try to access the script yourself.](http://www2.scs.ryerson.ca/%7Ew3dixon/cgi-bin/lab4.cgi)

So I'm being blocked. Normally I'd contact the sys admin and get them to unblock me, but a working perl script is due tonight. (I also tried using a VPN, it was blocked as well).

My solution was to SSH with terminal on my mac and/or Putty on my PC into Ryerson's server and use the unix command 'lynx' to run my scripts (since they aren't blocking their own IPs).

I was having some success, until I tried to use the perl get method from an html form (I copy pasted a script from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_cgi.htm just to get started, to see if syntactically correct code would work properly with my lynx strategy).

So when I was working on my script using a terminal at the university (with google chrome), my scripts worked fine.

Ryerson (my university), doesn't have a remote access program set up (other than ssh), but is there a way to access my webpage through their servers on a GUI browser installed on my machine?

Comment: My not just set up a web server/perl on your PC?

Comment: Good plan B, but I can't be sure a script that runs on my server will run on theirs.

But I'm definitely going to start doing that now. Googling now, but any recommendations? =

Comment: You could use SSH to tunnel a local port to remote localhost:80.  Something like this:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/112177/how-do-i-tunnel-and-browse-the-server-webpage-on-my-laptop

Comment: oooh, that's cool. Trying it now. ty!

Comment: Have you checked whether the file is world readable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An SSH tunnel is most likely the most feasible and easiest way to do what you want. Set up the tunnel like this:

```
ssh -L8080:www2.scs.ryerson.ca:80 username@www2.scs.ryerson.ca
```

If the www2 server is not the host you SSH to, simply replace the second instance of it in the command with the SSH server.

I use port `8080` here, as that alleviates you from needing `root` privileges.

Now, on your local workstation, in your browser, browse to:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: nuts, I'm getting an error from terminal when I try and look at port 8080
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
probably means I don't have permissions to do this.

Comment: yeah, I've searched the error, and it means I don't have permissions to do this. Still yours is the answer I was looking for so tyvm

Comment: Sometimes the sshd (the `ssh` daemon, i.e. the server side's end of your ssh connection) is configured to disallow ssh tunnels. Perhaps this is the case here.